# Return back server generated identifier in response with minimal changes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

My objective is to return back `HttpContext.TraceIdentifier` in the response header for all the APIs.

The return type of all APIs is `IActionResult`.

I've seen solutions for creating a `middlware` and overriding `messageHandler`.

I want to do minimal changes to just return it back.
Currently, I'm not interfering with the default message handler.

Comment: any update? Does my reply help you?

Comment: @BrandoZhang Thanks, this is a simple method, learnt a lot while understanding the ASP.NET execution flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you could try to use asp.net core action filter as global filter or as attribute to achieve your requirement.

You could get the httpcontext in the OnActionExecuted method and then you could register the filter for specific controller or as global filter.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

Create a action filter:

```
public class TestActionFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        var re =  context.HttpContext.TraceIdentifier;
        context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("TraceIdentifier", re);

    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {

 
        
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }


}
```

Add it as attribute in web api controller:

```
[TypeFilter(typeof(TestActionFilter))]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
```

Or register it as global filter:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddControllers(options=>options.Filters.Add(typeof(TestActionFilter)));
}
```

Result:

[image]